# Calculating azimuth of direction in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, measurements, azimuth

I am developing an application with OpenLayers and I need to calculate the angle between two segments or directions.

I thought about getting the azimuth of those segments and then calculate the difference but I cannot find any method that can perform this directly, something like ol/geom/LineString `getInitialAzimuth()` or similar.

I found this http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html that could be useful but I was expecting something simpler.

I am missing anything?

Comment: There's nothing simple about computing bearing in spheroidal coordinates.

Comment: `TurfJS`, https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@5/turf.min.js can be used. `turf.bearing()` is what you need. The difference between 2 bearings will be the angle.